# Can someone explain this return statement in the simplest words possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, return

I've stumbled upon some pretty powerful looking code. I had some trouble understanding the use of `get()` in a return statement and could use some guidance.

```
def operation(a, b):
    return {a+b: "added", a-b: "subtracted", a*b: "multiplied", a/b: "divided"}.get(24)
```

Comment: this is a dictionary where key is the evaluated operation (e.g., "a+b") and value is a description of what operation. `get` is a dictionary method that returns None if the key (24) is not present in the dict.

Comment: Dictionaries are the stuff wraped in curly brackets correct?

Comment: Yes, let me clarify. it's not returning a dict, it's returning the evaluated `get` method.

Comment: get accesses the keys which are operations if they are 24

Comment: So, I'm not sure what is the purpose of this function. Unless you expect `24` will be one of the keys, it's always going to return none.

Answer (score 2):

The function returns: *through what mathematical operation the result 24 can be reached from the 2 arguments `a` and `b`*.

For example, calling `operation(20, 4)` will return `'added'` while calling `operation(26, 2)` will return `'subtracted'`.

Don't let the fact that it is all in one line confuse you. You can write any valid Python expression in a return statement. Let's look at a simplified version:

```py
def operation(a, b):
    d = {a+b: "added", a-b: "subtracted", a*b: "multiplied", a/b: "divided"}
    res = d.get(24)
    return res
```

What this does is:

- On the 2 arguments given, build a dictionary with the result of different mathematical operations on those 2 arguments.
- Then, try to [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) the result 24 from that dictionary.
- if it is present, return the name of the operation it was achieved through. If not, return `None`.

In general in Python, dicts are a nice way of breaking down `if/elif` structurese to a more readable code. For example your function is equivalent to:

```py
def operation(a, b):
    if a+b == 24:
        res = "added"
    elif a-b == 24:
        res = "subtracted"
    elif a*b == 24:
        res = "multiplied"
    elif a/b == 24:
        res = "divided"
    else:
        res = None
    return res
```

As you can see, the original code is much neater.